# Ajuda para simplificar consulta sql query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Tenho uma consulta sql enorme:

```
select
l.no_cidadao,
extract(year from l.dt_cad_individual) ano,
extract(month from l.dt_cad_individual) mes,
date_part('year',age(now(), l.dt_cad_individual)) diferenca
from
tb_unidade_saude p,
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta a,
tb_cds_prof as c,
tb_pessoa_fisica as d,
tb_equipe as e,
(SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no_cidadao
   ORDER BY st_atualizacao desc) AS linha
   FROM tb_cds_cad_individual) l
WHERE LINHA = 1
AND l.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = a.co_cds_cad_individual
and c.nu_cns = d.nu_cns
and c.co_seq_cds_prof = l.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and a.co_pergunta = 19
and a.st_resposta = 1
and c.nu_ine = e.nu_ine
and e.co_unidade_saude = p.co_ator_papel
and p.nu_cnes like '%".$cnes."%'
group by
p.nu_cnes, l.no_cidadao, l.dt_cad_individual, e.no_equipe
order by
e.no_equipe, l.no_cidadao, l.dt_cad_individual
```

Isso tudo para me retornar uma lista de nomes das mulheres que estão gestantes em um sistema.

Após listar todas elas, preciso fazer tudo de novo para ver quais delas tiveram uma consulta marcada em um determinado mês:

```
select
p.nu_cnes,
a.no_cidadao,
count(case when(extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAtual." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAtual." and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl) then a.no_cidadao else null end) as a2,
count(case when(extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAnterior." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAnterior." and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl) then a.no_cidadao else null end) as a1
from
tb_unidade_saude p,
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta e,
tb_cds_prof as g,
tb_equipe as f,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d,
tb_cds_atend_individual b,
(SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no_cidadao
   ORDER BY st_atualizacao desc) AS linha
   FROM tb_cds_cad_individual) a
WHERE LINHA = 1
AND a.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = e.co_cds_cad_individual
and g.co_seq_cds_prof = a.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and e.co_pergunta = 19
and e.st_resposta = 1
and g.nu_ine = f.nu_ine
and f.co_unidade_saude = p.co_ator_papel
and a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
and ((extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAtual." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAtual.")
or (extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAnterior." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAnterior."))
and p.nu_cnes like '%".$cnes."%'
group by
p.nu_cnes, f.no_equipe, a.no_cidadao
order by
a.no_cidadao
```

Depois dessa, tem mais outras que usam a mesma lista de gestantes para pegar outras informações sobre as mesmas.

O que quero é o seguinte: uma vez que tenho a lista de gestantes na primeira consulta, como fazer a segunda consulta comparando com a primeira para economizar processamento, tipo assim:

```
select * from ... where no_cidadao in [lista da primeira consulta]
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode rodar uma consulta sobre outra consulta. Por exemplo, supondo que você tenha essas duas consultas, onde a segunda é basicamente uma cópia da primeira com mais um refinamento.

### Forma bruta

Transforme:

```
select
    foo, bar
from
    mulheres
where
    gravida = 1
    and cadastro_ativo = 1
    and... -- 500 condicoes aqui

--------------------------------------

select
    foo, bar, ni
from
    mulheres
    inner join consultas on consultas.mulher = mulheres.id
where
    mulheres.gravida = 1
    and mulheres.cadastro_ativo = 1
    and... -- 500 condicoes aqui
    and consultas.data > getdate()
```

Em:

```
select
    foo, bar, ni
from
    mulheres inner join consultas on consultas.mulher = mulheres.id
where
    consultas.data > getdate()
    and mulheres.id in (
        select
            foo, bar
        from
            mulheres
        where
            gravida = 1
            and cadastro_ativo = 1
            and... -- 500 condicoes aqui
    )
```

Você ainda vai ter uma montanha de código, mas vai ser uma montanha menor do que a que você tem hoje. Desvantagem: a complexidade na melhor das hipóteses permanece a mesma, mas em geral aumenta.

### Forma elegante

Siga os seguintes passos:

- Transforme a primeira consulta em uma View.
- Faça join dessa view com a segunda consulta, adicionando somente as condições que elas não tem em comum.
- Encapsule tudo em uma stored procedure, para facilitar ao banco a otimização das consultas.
- Não esqueça de indexar os campos utilizados com mais frequência para as pesquisa.
- Havendo uma linguagem de programação em um nível acima na aplicação, talvez você possa transferir parte da lógica para o nível superior.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode armazenar o resultado dessas queries com o [**With**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html):

```
with gravidas as (
    select
    l.no_cidadao,
    extract(year from l.dt_cad_individual) ano,
    extract(month from l.dt_cad_individual) mes,
    date_part('year',age(now(), l.dt_cad_individual)) diferenca
    from
    tb_unidade_saude p,
    tb_cds_cidadao_resposta a,
    tb_cds_prof as c,
    tb_pessoa_fisica as d,
    tb_equipe as e,
    (SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no_cidadao
       ORDER BY st_atualizacao desc) AS linha
       FROM tb_cds_cad_individual) l
    WHERE LINHA = 1
    AND l.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = a.co_cds_cad_individual
    and c.nu_cns = d.nu_cns
    and c.co_seq_cds_prof = l.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
    and a.co_pergunta = 19
    and a.st_resposta = 1
    and c.nu_ine = e.nu_ine
    and e.co_unidade_saude = p.co_ator_papel
    and p.nu_cnes like '%".$cnes."%'
    group by
    p.nu_cnes, l.no_cidadao, l.dt_cad_individual, e.no_equipe
    order by
    e.no_equipe, l.no_cidadao, l.dt_cad_individual), 

atendidas as (

    select
p.nu_cnes,
a.no_cidadao,
count(case when(extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAtual." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAtual." and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl) then a.no_cidadao else null end) as a2,
count(case when(extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAnterior." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAnterior." and b.co_cds_ficha_atend_individual = d.co_seq_cds_ficha_atend_indivdl) then a.no_cidadao else null end) as a1
from
tb_unidade_saude p,
tb_cds_cidadao_resposta e,
tb_cds_prof as g,
tb_equipe as f,
tb_cds_ficha_atend_individual d,
tb_cds_atend_individual b,
(SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY no_cidadao
   ORDER BY st_atualizacao desc) AS linha
   FROM tb_cds_cad_individual) a
WHERE LINHA = 1
AND a.co_seq_cds_cad_individual = e.co_cds_cad_individual
and g.co_seq_cds_prof = a.co_cds_prof_cadastrante
and e.co_pergunta = 19
and e.st_resposta = 1
and g.nu_ine = f.nu_ine
and f.co_unidade_saude = p.co_ator_papel
and a.nu_cns_cidadao = b.nu_cartao_sus
and ((extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAtual." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAtual.")
or (extract(month from d.dt_ficha) = ".$mesAnterior." and extract(year from d.dt_ficha) = ".$anoAnterior."))
and p.nu_cnes like '%".$cnes."%'
group by
p.nu_cnes, f.no_equipe, a.no_cidadao
order by
a.no_cidadao)



select * from gravidas;

select * from atendidas;
```

> A segunda query já poderia ser simplificada com os resultados da primeira, mas aí preciso entender todo seu select antes